# Average values for a cell containing both number and text - Excel

Tags: excel

I have a drop-down list in several cells (G13:P13) that contain both text and a number. Example: 5 - Excellent Progress 4 - Above Average Progress 3 - Average Progress 2 - Below Average Progress 1 - Not Making Expected Progress

I've been trying to average these values and ignore text and haven't had any luck with the formulas I've tried thus far. I know I probably need to use LEFT and VALUE, but I'm not an Excel pro and am struggling a bit. Any advice or a formula that would work would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: how many digits your numbers can contain? only one or numbers >=10 also possible? Also could your cell contain negative numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of your fields follow the format: number value, followed by " - " and designation, use the following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(LEFT(G13:P13,FIND(" - ",G13:P13)-1)))
```

Since it's an array formula, you'll need to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.